# Add a fixed letter to all equation numbers

Tags: equations, numbering

I am working on a supplementary for an article and I want the equation in this supplementary to have the letter "S" before the numbers of the equations (i.e. equations `(S1)`, `(S2)`, etc, instead of `(1)`, `(2)`, etc). I know I can do this for every equation separately by using `\tag{}`, but since I have many equations I am looking for an automated way.

Comment: \renewcommand\theequation{S\arabic{equation}}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There seems to be no answer on the site that contains `\renewcommand` and `\theequation`, so an answer seems due.

Comment: @egreg actually, I think I would say that this one does it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88857/custom-automatic-equation-numbering Voting to close as a duplicate :)

Comment: @cmhughes The searching facility is betraying me.

Comment: @egreg I think the title of the current question is much better than the duplicate- perhaps once this is closed we can edit accordingly...