# Changing the format of figure, algorithm and equation numbering

Tags: formatting, numbering

This is a follow-up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112865/automatically-add-prefix-to-references-from-another-document) question. That allowed me to format references to an equation/figure/algorithm so that they started with an 'S'. What if I want to change the format in the original equation/figure/algorithm? For instance, if I entered

```
\begin{equation}
a=b
\label{eq:myeq}
\end{equation}
```

How would I get it to show up in the final document as:

```
a=b (S1)
```

Instead of:

```
a=b (1)
```

?

Comment: have you seen [custom automatic equation numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88857)

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: No, that mostly answers it, but equations are still being indexed from 0 instead of 1 for some reason.

Comment: I am using `hyperref`.

Comment: Would you be able to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? The default behaviour would be to start the numbering of equations at 1, not 0.

Comment: Found my error, explained in the comments for the answer below. Given this answer is the same as the link from @cmhughes, should this question be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\def\theequation{S\arabic{equation}}
```

I assume that you use it in `article`. Definition for `report` or `book` should be a bit modified.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\theequation{S\arabic{equation}}

\begin{equation}
2+2=4
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]