# Using \section*{} messes up equation numbering?

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,fleqn]{article}

\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}    
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textheight=9in, textwidth=6.5in}
\usepackage{amssymb}                                         
\usepackage{amsmath}                                         

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\parindent = 0.0in
\parskip = 0.2in

\begin{document}

\section*{New Section}
\hrule

Text    

\begin{align}
 \phi =& \int_S \mathrm{d}a\\     
 =& \int_S f(u, v) |\mathbf{T}_u \times \mathbf{T}_v| \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I don't want the number to be in front of "New Section", so I am using the asterisk `\section*{New Section}` but I do want the equations to be numbered as (1.1) and (1.2) etc.  However, I have found that using the asterisk sets the equation numbers to (0.1) and (0.2) and I have yet to find a way around this.

Comment: How will the reader know that you are in section 1, _etc._ without section numbers?

Comment: Maybe [this tex.stackexchange answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/adding-letters-to-equation-numbers) is what you are looking for, although it doesn't automatically number the equations. Another option may be [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88857/custom-automatic-equation-numbering).

Comment: No section number? The equations can't be numbered according to a number that doesn't exist. Leave out the `\numberwithin` instruction which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}\section*{#1}}
```

before your first section. Then use

```
\mysection{New Section}
```

This code works:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textheight=9in, textwidth=6.5in}
\usepackage{amssymb}                                         
\usepackage{amsmath}                                         

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\parindent = 0.0in
\parskip = 0.2in

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}\section*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\mysection{New Section}
\hrule
Text

\begin{align}
 \phi =& \int_S \mathrm{d}a\\     
 =& \int_S f(u, v) |\mathbf{T}_u \times \mathbf{T}_v| \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align}

\end{document}
```